# Heroku showing error for typescript and React.JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I just learnt Typescript and tried to push it to Heroku to run online. However, I got this problem. Can anyone help me what is wrong with the configuration? I already have a Profile with web: npm start.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.54",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.46",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I tried to run it on heroku, these error shows up. Can anyone help me point out where I get wrong on the code? Thank you.

```
2020-08-20T02:04:52.768419+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user kevxxxxx
2020-08-20T02:04:52.768419+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user kevkxxxxx
2020-08-20T02:04:52.863227+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user kevkwxxxx
2020-08-20T02:04:52.863227+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user kevkwxxxx
2020-08-20T02:05:02.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user kevkwxxxx
2020-08-20T02:06:24.621179+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user kevkwxxxx
2020-08-20T02:06:24.621179+00:00 app[api]: Deploy b542e4e6 by user kevkwxxxx
2020-08-20T02:06:24.637255+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user kevkwxxxx
2020-08-20T02:06:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-08-20T02:06:33.778274+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-08-20T02:06:37.345544+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-20T02:06:37.345569+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-app@0.1.0 start /app
2020-08-20T02:06:37.345570+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-08-20T02:06:37.345570+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-20T02:06:40.190225+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.16.1.122/
2020-08-20T02:06:40.190782+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-08-20T02:06:40.190901+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-08-20T02:06:40.191007+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-08-20T02:06:40.191239+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-08-20T02:06:40.191239+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-20T02:06:40.320581+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-08-20T02:06:40.357851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-20T02:06:40.361139+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-20T02:06:48.334774+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-08-20T02:06:50.949971+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-20T02:06:50.949997+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-app@0.1.0 start /app
2020-08-20T02:06:50.949997+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-08-20T02:06:50.949998+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-20T02:06:53.410228+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.19.104.146/
2020-08-20T02:06:53.410751+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-08-20T02:06:53.410902+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ��wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-08-20T02:06:53.411003+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-08-20T02:06:53.411229+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-08-20T02:06:53.411231+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-20T02:06:53.535298+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-08-20T02:06:53.573752+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-20T02:06:54.608604+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=guarded-depths-86821.herokuapp.com request_id=a715a5b6-5ebd-46a1-bc83-e5af1a8adf93 fwd="98.252.127.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-20T02:06:55.888464+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=guarded-depths-86821.herokuapp.com request_id=1c2e5980-a5b3-4a14-93b5-76ab3a8a4e1f fwd="98.252.127.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-20T02:15:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user kevkwoxxxxx
2020-08-20T02:16:25.020488+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 96a06fc7 by user kevkwoxxxx
2020-08-20T02:16:25.020488+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user kevkwxxxx
2020-08-20T02:16:25.756806+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-20T02:16:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-08-20T02:16:38.637718+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-08-20T02:16:44.452152+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-20T02:16:44.452164+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-app@0.1.0 start /app
2020-08-20T02:16:44.452164+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-08-20T02:16:44.452164+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-20T02:16:46.910272+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.19.70.186/
2020-08-20T02:16:46.910678+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-08-20T02:16:46.910753+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-08-20T02:16:46.910818+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-08-20T02:16:46.910981+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-08-20T02:16:46.910981+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-20T02:16:47.027054+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-08-20T02:16:47.064473+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-20T02:16:49.868294+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=guarded-depths-86821.herokuapp.com request_id=2fa4ba33-25e5-4954-96c1-0ae870df9733 fwd="98.252.127.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-20T02:18:16.488972+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-20T02:18:25.931282+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-08-20T02:18:29.027258+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-20T02:18:29.027291+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-app@0.1.0 start /app
2020-08-20T02:18:29.027292+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-08-20T02:18:29.027292+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-20T02:18:32.269220+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.23.86/
2020-08-20T02:18:32.269587+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-08-20T02:18:32.269687+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-08-20T02:18:32.269808+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-08-20T02:18:32.270062+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-08-20T02:18:32.270063+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-20T02:18:32.371853+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-08-20T02:18:32.411618+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-20T02:18:49.691244+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=guarded-depths-86821.herokuapp.com request_id=b04d3419-ee10-4063-865f-d34ed4aee58e fwd="98.252.127.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: there is an error code of `H10` in that log. did you Google it to see what it was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Webpack dev server. That server is not production ready and has a lot of different confiurations.

In simple words, in React, you use `npm start` to launch your app on your dev server. If you want to host your app, then you first build the artifacts by running `npm run build` which will generate all the artifacts in the `dist` folder in your application. Then, you take the contents from the `dist` directory and deploy it on a server.

To deploy it anywhere, you will need a server to host your files. Heroku, however has automated some of the deployment process for hosting apps.

Check [this](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration) blog published by the Heroku team which shows how you can deploy the application with ZERO config.